# displaying page titles in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm developing an app using `ViewPager` and `TitlePageIndicator` of the `ViewPagerIndicator`. I'm using `PagerTitleStrip` to display the title of each page as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The titles are being displayed below the `TitlePageIndicator`, but I would like the titles to appear above the `TitlePageIndicator`. Is it possible to do so? Presently I'm using `PagerTitleStrip` to display the titles.

The layout of the main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
android:id="@+id/titles"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@id/titles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will be easier if you use android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip instead,like

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I used PagerTabStrip and it works like `TitlePageIndicator`. So it seems I do not need to use `TitlePageIndicator` anymore.